# Wordpress Javascript displaying an image Question

Tags: images, javascript

I think i may be getting a little confused, but I have a list and a select button on each line.  When the user clicks the button a modal shows up and I am trying to simple get an image (with a post_id) to display.

So in PHP I have this:

```
<img id="changeImage"src="
<?php 
    echo $v[0]->user_image_id ? 
        wp_get_attachment_image_src( $v[0]->user_image_id,
            array( 'width' => 75, 'height' => 75 ))[0] :
            wp_get_attachment_url( 259 ); ?>" style="width: 75px; height: 75px"/>
```

This is part of the list, so each picture (avatar) is shown.  Then a button is clicked and I already have the `post_id` with this code:

```
$('.selectedBtn').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var elm = $(this);
            var data;
            var dataArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('dataArray'));
            $.each(dataArray, function(k, v) {
                if(parseInt(v[0].wyol_list_id) === elm.data('wd')) {
                    data = v[0];
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#wd_request_shoppers_name').text(v[0].user_name);
                    $('#wd_request_store').text(v[0].wd_store);
                    var imgid = v[0].user_image_id ? v[0].user_image_id : 259;
                    console.log(wp.media());
                    // USAGE:
                    preloadAttachment(imgid, function (attachment) {
                        console.log(attachment.get('url'));
                        console.log(wp.media.attachment(imgid).get('url')); // this also works
                    });
                        $('#wd_request_shoppers_image').prop('src',  wp.media.attachment(imgid).get('url'));
                            v[0].instructions ? $('#wd_request_shoppers_detail').text(v[0].instructions) : '';
                            $('#exampleModal1').foundation('open');
                        }
                    });
                    //console.log(elm.data('wd'));
                });
                $('#closeModal').on('click', function () {
                    $('#exampleModal1').foundation('close');
                });
            });
```

But all I get is this console.log error:

(index):352 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attachment' of undefined

On this line:
   352 if (wp.media.attachment(ID).get('url')) {

So has WP not got the ability to grab a url in WP?

Thanks in advance

Addy

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `wp_enqueue_media()` else the `wp` object won't have a `media` option.

For example, go to WP Admin and pull up the JS console and type `wp.media` on the dashboard, it won't work. Try again on the media page, and this time it will work.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media

> To be able to use the JavaScript-API, you first have to init all the needed JavaScript-Libraries and Styles:
>
> ```
> wp_enqueue_media();
> ```

Comment: thank you, but I am getting console response of "undefined" on both?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Tom, I managed to get this working by using the `wp.media.model` which ended up like this:

```
var attachment = new wp.media.model.Attachment.get(imgid);
                    attachment.fetch({
                        success: function (att) {
                            if (_.contains(['png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg'], att.get('subtype'))) {
                                //console.log(att.attributes);
                                $("#wd_request_shoppers_image").attr("src", att.attributes.sizes.thumbnail.url);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Not sure it's the quickest way of doing it, but works.

Hope it helps others.